# An expression to describe a person who ensures members of a group receive less favourable treatment

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that describes when:

A single person in a group receives a less favorable treatment compared to other group members. The person's solution is to make sure everyone else also receives the unfavorable treatment rather than he/she to receive the better treatment.

In a sense, pulling everyone down or pulling everyone back.

I'm trying to find a word or phrase that describes this situation.

Comment: levelling the playing field? I actually think you've basically answered your own question as I would have suggested 'bringing everyone down'.

Comment: *Inter alia*, I found [*Union labor is a **leveler-up** of men, not a **leveler-down**; the servant, not the master*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+leveler-up+of+men%22), and [*The apostles of the open shop contend that collective bargaining is a **leveler down**, but as a matter of fact the leveling down process is mostly practiced by them, and various devices and schemes are employed to that end.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bargaining+is+a+leveler+down%22) So I'd say you can successfully insult your target just by calling him a ***leveler-down***.

Comment: ...personally I think that ***lowest common denominizer*** would be good - as yet it doesn't seem to have any currency, but it does include suitably pejorative elements, which I assume is what you're looking for. And *in context*, you'd expect it to be understood.

Comment: Isn’t it more common for the one feeling slighted to complain to “the powers that be” that everyone should be treated equally (hoping for his treatment to move to par) and then have it backfire when “the powers that be” say, “you want equal treatment? Fine, All of you will now lose.” And then the complainer gets the wrath of the group directed at him, saying he’s not a team player, that he should have shut-up and taken one for the team, etc.

Comment: Various idioms like cutting off your nose to spite your face; search SE.

Answer (score 1):

Crab mentality or crab bucket thinking.

Briefly, "[Crab Mentality](https://effectiviology.com/crab-mentality/): When People Pull Down Those Who Get Ahead" put, it's someone holding other people back:

> ...crab mentality can cause someone to discourage or sabotage their
> friend who is starting to do well at school, simply because they’re
> bitter about struggling with their own studies.
>
> The name of this phenomenon comes from a story about crabs in a
> bucket, who fail to escape because they [the other crabs, all the crabs] keep pulling back any crab who
> manages to get to the top.

It's the opposite of growth mentality. None of the crabs can get out of the bucket because they pull each other back down.  Easily summed as ["If I can't have it, neither can you."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_mentality#:%7E:text=Crab%20mentality%2C%20also%20known%20as,it%2C%20neither%20can%20you%22.) Another phrase is "tall poppy syndrome."

Answer (score 0):

How about [collective punishment](https://www.google.com/search?q=group%20punishment)?

unless you mean the process of bringing that upon everyone else - in which case you would be inviting or encouraging it perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As a single word, such a person might be referred to as "**vindictive**".

Perhaps you are thinking in terms of the idiom "**misery loves company**". It's an old proverb. One that apparently goes back to the time of Sophocles - around 408 BCE. The proverb means that **miserable people like others to be miserable too**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vindictive

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Misery+Loves+Company

Answer (score 0):

a **saboteur**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/saboteur)

> One who commits sabotage (the deliberate attempt to damage, destroy,
>   or hinder a cause or activity)

As in:

> In a sense, he was our **saboteur**, pulling everyone down and dooming
>   our efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Or, even consider the casual, "If Mama not happy, ain't nobody happy."

Although origin & first-use seem lost to history, I've heard it all my life here in America. Used as friendly, supportive(w/wink), commiserate wisdom in a "kinda-funny-but-not-good-situation-within-a-group"...even if the gender involved is male. "Mama" is interchangeable w/other roles.

Example:  "If baby not happy, ain't nobody happy!"  "If granny not happy, ain't nobody happy!"  "If First Lady not happy, ain't nobody happy!"  (etc., etc.)

Comment: Sounds appropriate, Suzanne, but can you clarify the meaning, please. Does 'Mama' etc go out of their way to make sure everyone suffers along with her? Or is it more automatic?

Comment: Excellent point.  In MY PERSONAL opinion and use:  although the implicit meaning may lean toward intent to spread the suffering (in order to resolve/get her way), human vibes between the lines -- the nuance of usage -- there's always a kind of "wink"...and a nod, because everyone KNOWS they need to get her happy so they can have some peace. It's their job...so get started, folks!  The same when it's used with infants, spoiled children, First Wives, lol.  

Logical (-ish)?  I love American English & idioms are fascinating. Thanks for a great question. I hope this is helpful to you!